# targetsdkversion Market visibility problem Android

Tags: android, google-play

My app uses 2.0 sdks (bluetooth toggle and service api changes) and in the manifest has

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="5" />
```

It runs perfectly fine on 1.5/1.6 devices, but when I uploaded it to the Market, it no longer shows up on 1.5/1.6 phones

Please help!